# Config sub-folder in Thymelaf Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I configure **thymeleaf**  to recognize *view/htmls* under sub-folder?

I have `templates/` folder right now and all my view HTML pages are found in this single folder.

Comment: By default spring boot searches for all files and folders under resources. So everything should be findable. Do you have any problem?

Comment: really so i shoud go  a head and create subfolder ad put view files there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default spring-boot searches for all files and folders under resources. So feel free to create subfolder for example under `templates/`.

You just have to set the folder structure to your returning `view` or of your fragments in `html`.

Just an example of a project from me:

[image]

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getAnyWellBox")
public String getAnyWellBox(Model model)
    //any code
    return "thirdparty/booking/map/well-box";
}
```

Comment: what about I have a controller class and all methods in it will return html under  `thirdparty` folder, then do we have to set `return "thirdparty/a.html`, `return "thirdparty/b.html`? could we just define `thirdparty` once and all the methods in this controller will lookup template files in `thirdparty` folder?